# Converting a string consisting of three types of data types to a list

Tags: haskell

I have the following datatypes:

```
-- 1.1
data LineItem = Space | Newline | Word String
    deriving (Eq)

-- 1.2
mkSpace :: LineItem
mkSpace = Space

mkNewline :: LineItem
mkNewline = Newline

mkWord :: String -> LineItem
mkWord = Word 

-- 1.3
lineItemToStr :: LineItem -> String
lineItemToStr Space = show " "
lineItemToStr Newline = show "\n"
lineItemToStr (Word s1) = show s1

instance Show LineItem where
    show = lineItemToStr
```

Given a String I have to convert it to a list where each element of the list is one of the datatypes. What I have so far is:

```
toLineItems :: String -> [LineItem]
toLineItems (' ':rest) = Space : toLineItems rest
toLineItems ('\n':rest) = Newline : toLineItems rest
toLineItems "" = []
toLineItems (w:rest) = mkWord w : toLineItems rest -- this one is obviously wrong
```

My confusion so far is how I handle the occasion where the head is a char. I would think that I accumulate the chars until the head is no longer a letter and then append it as one word. But I'm not quite sure how you would go around matching that pattern in Haskell.

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Comment: Unrelated: in `lineItemToStr` you might have used `show` too many times, depending on the actual wanted output. If you happen to observe that the output contains strings which are more escaped than wanted, remove some `show` there. For instance `show " "` is equivalent to `"\" \""`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `span` to split the rest of the string into a leading word and the rest:

```hs
toLineItems s = let (w, rest) = span (not . (`elem` "\n ")) s
                 in mkWord w : toLineItems rest
```

`` not . (`elem` "\n ") `` is a function which returns `True` for all `Char`s which are not `' '` or `'\n'`,
and `span` takes as many as it can fulfilling that predicate and puts them in the first element of the tuple and puts the remaining ones in the other tuple element.

Comment: Kinda new to Haskell so function composition is a bit of a mystery, is my interpretation correct:
You create two lists, one for the word up until a \n (or " "?) occurence and the rest, which you store respectively in w & rest?

Comment: Thanks a lot, your edit explains it splendidly!

Comment: Note that the `Data.List` offers `break` as a negated `span`, so ``... = break (`elem` "\n ") s in ...`` might be more common.

Comment: ``(`notElem` "\n ")`` is also available from the prelude.

Answer (score 1):

A `String` is just a list of `Char` values. Wrap `w` in a list before passing it to `mkWord`.

```
toLineItems (w:rest) = mkWord [w] : toLineItems rest
```

Comment: That's quite useful thank you. However using your method I would get for toLineItems "Just a test" = ["J","u","s",...], but I would like to have each word together so ["Just", " ", "a",..]

Comment: I could add an extra parameter that keeps track of all the strings up until " " or " \n" occurence I suppose, but I'm completely clueless how to implement this without an extra parameter.

Comment: Then you don't want to operate on the input string directly, but on the result of `words` applied to that string. (`words "Just a line" == ["Just", "a", "line"]`)

Comment: (Or something similar to `words` which also preserves the whitespace used to delimit words, `somethingElse "Just a line" == ["Just", " ", "a", " ", "line"]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the approach using only pattern matching:

```
toLineItems :: String -> String ->  [LineItem]
toLineItems (' ':rest) [] = Space : toLineItems rest
toLineItems (' ':rest) acc = mkWord (reverse acc) : Space : toLineItems rest
toLineItems ('\n':rest) [] = Newline : toLineItems rest
toLineItems ('\n':rest) acc = mkWord (reverse acc) : Newline : toLineItems rest
toLineItems [] [] = []
toLineItems [] acc = mkWord (reverse acc)
toLineItems (w:rest) acc = toLineItems rest (w:acc)
```

Here we introduce an accumulator and match on it.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for posting a complete, self-contained example, so we could duplicate your problem.  I want to point out a few things in your "background" code (the part that was already working) that most Haskellers would consider bad practice, and I also have a long explanation of how to attack these problems in general, if you don't have a `span` or `break` function to help.

As for the "bad practice" items, if you wrote this code, consider it some advice to up your Haskell game.  If this code was given to you as part of an exercise, consider it a warning that not everyone who teaches Haskell has a firm grasp of best practices for programming Haskell.  Here's my advice:

- Don't define `mkSpace`, `mkNewline`, and `mkWord` synonyms for the constructors `Space`, `Newline`, and `Word`.  This is not idiomatic and is likely to be considered bad practice by nearly all experienced Haskell programmers.  In your own code, you don't use these consistently anyway: `toLineItems` uses the function `mkWord` to make a `Word`, but it uses `Space` and `Newline` directly to make those corresponding values.  You should just use the `Word` constructor directly, too.  It's called a "constructor" for a reason!
- Don't write a `Show` instance that misrepresents the data structure being shown.  In particular, with your `Show` instance in place the desired output of `lineItemToStr "hello world"` is:

  ```
  ghci> lineItemToStr "hello world"
  ["hello"," ","world"]
  ```

  If your code is buggy and codes spaces as `Word " "` instead of `Space`, the output will instead be:

  ```
  ghci> lineItemToStr "hello world"
  ["hello"," ","world"]
  ```

  If you can't tell the difference between the correct and incorrect outputs, well... that's the problem.  Having a "pretty printing" function like `lineItemToStr` is great, but you should delete the `Show` instance and derive one instead (`... deriving (Show, Eq)`).  That way, the correct output will be easy to verify:

  ```
  ghci> toLineItems "hello world"
  [Word "hello",Space,Word "world"]
  ```

With that advice out of the way, the accepted answer, using `span` or `break`, would be the usual way of writing this function in real code, but it's important to understand how to handle this *sort* of problem using a direct recursive solution.  There are two main approaches.  One involves post-processing the results of the recursive call, the other involves introducing a helper function with an "accumulator".  Both are a little tricky to get right, but you should make sure they're both in your Haskell toolbox.

The **post-processing solution** works like this.  Suppose we are trying to write the final case for `toLineItems` where we have already handled the space and newline cases.  We pattern match on `c:rest`, where `c` is some non-space, non-newline character:

```
toLineItems (c:rest) = ...
```

and we know that we could make the recursive call `toLineItems rest`.  Let's imagine we're at the beginning of the `"hello world"` example.  Then, we have:

```
c = 'h'
rest = "ello world"
```

and, assuming our function `toLineItems` actually works, the recursive call would give:

```
toLineItems rest = [Word "ello",Space,Word "world"]
```

How can we "fix" this answer to give us the correct result?  Well, we can use a `case` construct to extract the first `Word "ello"` from the recursive call and add the `'h'` character:

```
toLineItems (c:rest) = case toLineItems rest of
    (Word w : moreitems) -> Word (c:w) : moreitems
```

Similarly, if we were parsing `toLineItems "ello world"` with the `toLineItems (c:rest)` case, we would have:

```
c = 'e'
rest = "llo world"
-- result of recursive call:
toLineItems rest = [Word "llo",Space,Word "world"]
```

and the above `case` would correctly fix up the result of the recursive call to yield:

```
Word (c:w) : moreitems = [Word "ello",Space,Word "world"]
```

That takes care of the tricky case of adding the parsed character 'c' to the rest of a word.  To take care of the other cases, consider what happens for `toLineItems "o world"`, where we have:

```
c = 'o'
rest = " world"
-- result of recursive call:
toLineItems rest = [Space,Word "world"]
```

The correct answer for `toLineItems "o world"` is:

```
[Word "o",Space,Word "world"]
```

so we need a case like:

```
toLineItems (c:rest) = case toLineItems rest of
    ...
    (Space : moreitems) -> Word [c] : Space : moreitems
```

Similarly, for `Newline`:

```
    (Newline : moreitems) -> Word [c] : Newline : moreitems
```

The remaining case handles the end of string:

```
    [] -> Word [c] : []
```

If you've got a good eye, you'll see that all three of these cases can be handled by a single case, giving the answer:

```
toLineItems (c:rest) = case toLineItems rest of
    (Word w : moreitems) -> Word (c:w) : moreitems
    moreitems -> Word [c] : moreitems
```

Try out the complete definition:

```
toLineItems :: String -> [LineItem]
toLineItems (' ':rest) = Space : toLineItems rest
toLineItems ('\n':rest) = Newline : toLineItems rest
toLineItems "" = []
toLineItems (c:rest) = case toLineItems rest of
    (Word w : moreitems) -> Word (c:w) : moreitems
    moreitems -> Word [c] : moreitems
```

and you'll see it works just fine.

The **accumulator** solution works like this.  The idea is to write a helper function that gets invoked at the start of a word and uses an extra parameter, an "accumulator", to keep track of the work done so far (i.e., the characters of the word read so far).  It "loops" by making recursive calls that add to this accumulator, and when it identifies the end of the word, it returns the accumulator value as the final answer.  After handling the space and newline cases, we can invoke this helper with an empty accumulator:

```
toLineItems str = readWord "" str   -- first arg is accumulator
```

The helper function should first check for the "end of word", being careful not to drop the space or newline that ends the word when it passes control back to `toLineItems`.

```
readWord acc (' ':rest) = Word acc : toLineItems (' ':rest)
readWord acc ('\n':rest) = Word acc : toLineItems ('\n':rest)
readWord acc [] = Word acc : toLineItems []
```

and otherwise add the next character to the accumulator and call itself:

```
readWord acc (c:rest) = readWord (acc ++ [c]) rest
```

This gives the solution:

```
toLineItems :: String -> [LineItem]
toLineItems (' ':rest) = Space : toLineItems rest
toLineItems ('\n':rest) = Newline : toLineItems rest
toLineItems "" = []
toLineItems str = readWord "" str
  where
    readWord acc (' ':rest) = Word acc : toLineItems (' ':rest)
    readWord acc ('\n':rest) = Word acc : toLineItems ('\n':rest)
    readWord acc [] = Word acc : toLineItems []
    readWord acc (c:rest) = readWord (acc ++ [c]) rest
```

which also works fine.  It is not the most efficient solution:

- At the start of the word, the first character -- which is already known to not be a space or a newline from matching by `toLineItems` is re-checked by `readWord`.
- Accumulating a list by adding characters to the end with `acc ++ [c]` is very inefficient in Haskell.
- The first three patterns in `readWord` involve a lot of unnecessary duplication, since they all do roughly the same thing -- return `Word acc` and parse the rest with `toLineItems`.  This is less an issue for program efficiency and more an issue of violating the DRY principle, making review of the code inefficient.

Here's a solution that addresses these problems:

```
toLineItems :: String -> [LineItem]
toLineItems (' ':rest) = Space : toLineItems rest
toLineItems ('\n':rest) = Newline : toLineItems rest
toLineItems "" = []
toLineItems (c:rest)= readWord [c] rest  -- we know `c` is not whitespace
  where
    -- note: accumulator is reversed, because repeated `c:acc` is more
    -- efficient than `acc ++ [c]`
    readWord acc (c:rest) | c `notElem` " \n" = readWord (c:acc) rest
    readWord acc rest = Word (reverse acc) : toLineItems rest
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried to go through your entire comment and got a couple of questions: firstly you state that adding a mkSpace etc constructor is redundant for your data types (I assume this is the correct term in Haskell?). So Space is equivalent to mkSpace right and there's no reason to define mkSpace (whether it be more secure or whatever?)

Comment: As for defining the Show instance, this was part of the exercise. I realize that it's rather better to derive Show. I have also decided to use ```break```, your example of solving it recursively was a nice addition though, thank you.

Comment: Also we aren't allowed to add "extra parameters" or change the function header (I assume this is the right terminology?). So I can't use an accumulator which for me personally would have made the problem a lot easier. As you probably have noticed I'm an absolute beginner at Haskell so your comment cleared up a lot of things, thank you a lot for your time and effort!

Comment: With respect to extra parameters, it's very common in Haskell code to define helper functions like `readWord` either at the top level or in a `where` clause to handle the extra parameters without changing the main function signature.  Check with your instructor.  They may want to prohibit helper functions for certain exercises, but a blanket prohibition on dividing your program up into multiple functions would be sad -- like learning C without pointers, Java without objects, or Python without indentation.

Comment: Yes, the `mkXxx` are redundant. They aren't quite equivalent, for example `Space` can be used as a pattern (e.g., `case item of Space -> ...` or `foo Space = ...`) while `mkSpace` can't.  But, when constructing values in an expression, `mkSpace` is more or less equivalent to `Space`. Your instructor probably has some (misguided) pedagogical reason for having you define `mkXxx` functions like this, so you might have to include them in your assignments, but it's not considered good practice. (Where a `mkXxx`-like function is used to construct a value, it should be done for a good reason.)